# Two "one-to-one" references to same table in SQLAlchemy

Tags: sqlalchemy

Suppose I am modelling postal address changes. I'd like each `AddressChange` to have a `before` relationship to an `Address`, as well as an `after` relationship to another `Address`. And I'd like a reference back from the `Address` to the `AddressChange` it is associated with.

```
class AddressChange(Base):
  __tablename__ = 'AddressChanges'

  id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)

  before_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('Addresses.id'))
  before = relationship('Address', foreign_keys=before_id, uselist=False,
    back_populates='change')

  after_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('Addresses.id'))
  after = relationship('Address', foreign_keys=after_id, uselist=False,
    back_populates='change')


class Address(Base):
  __tablename__ = 'Addresses'

  id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
  street, city, etc = Column(String), Column(String), Column(String)

  change = relationship('AddressChange')
```

However SQLAlchemy complains:

> Could not determine join condition between parent/child tables on relationship Address.change - there are multiple foreign key paths linking the tables.  Specify the 'foreign_keys' argument, providing a list of those columns which should be counted as containing a foreign key reference to the parent table.

My `Address` does not *have* a foreign key reference to the parent table, and it's not clear to me why it should need one. If I add one, I get

> Address.change and back-reference AddressChange.before are both of the same direction symbol('MANYTOONE').  Did you mean to set remote_side on the many-to-one side ?

Which is starting to get confusing, because the documentation for `remote_side` is for "self-referential relationships."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @alex-grönholm for helping on #sqlalchemy.

This can be solved by adding a `primaryjoin` parameter to `Address`'s side of the relationship to teach it how to map back to the parent `AddressChange`:

```
change = relationship('AddressChange', uselist=False,
  viewonly=True,
  primaryjoin=or_(
    AddressChange.before_id == id,
    AddressChange.after_id == id
  ))
```

Comment: I added `viewonly=True` after debugging with Elmer on IRC.